# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base [...] does not exist or is not a readable directory

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm getting the following error and I have no idea what it is, I'm new to servlets and tomcat server as well, so could you explain to me how do I identify errors such as the error below?. Any help is appreciated.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C: \Users\ agrosys\ workspace\.metadata\.plugins\ org.eclipse.wst.server.core\ tmp1\ wtpwebapps\ JqTree does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java: 136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java: 5145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java: 5330)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java: 150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java: 1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java: 1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The relevant line is ``java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C: \Users\ agrosys\ workspace\.metadata\.plugins\ org.eclipse.wst.server.core\ tmp1\ wtpwebapps\ JqTree does not exist or is not a readable directory``. Is ``JqTree`` the project you want to deploy? If so, does it build correctly in eclipse?

Comment: hmm interesting, thanks for helping, if you make your comment into an answer I'd be glad to set it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse can't read the directory where the project is so all the resources are not available when you're attempting to start the Tomcat Server. A few suggestions are as follows:

- *) Check permissions on the project folder and wtpwebapps.
- *) Check the OS user running tomcat and eclipse are able to read the

eclipse project folder.

- *) Make sure the tomcat plugin is reading the right directory for projects.
- *) Make sure your web project is deployed to the correct directory (wtpwebapps)

Comment: Although not the issue in OP's case, I've also seen this "failed to start" error when multiple servlet classes are listening at the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute Maven Clean on your project, maybe the Eclipse don't sent the project folder to Tomcat access.